# StructureMap - Get constructor dependencies via name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, ioc-container, structuremap

How can I get constructor dependencies via name when the class itself is does not need to get the concrete implementation via the name.

```
public class PriceValidator : IPriceValidator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPriceValidationRule> _priceValidationRules;

    public PriceValidator(IEnumerable<IPriceValidationRule> priceValidationRules)
    {
        _priceValidationRules = priceValidationRules;
    }

    public bool IsPriceValid(decimal price)
    {
        return _priceValidationRules.All(priceValidator => priceValidator.IsPriceValid(price));
    }
}
```

Call:

```
_priceValidator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPriceValidator>();
```

So I want a concrete implementation of IPriceValidator but with specific (by name) Validation Rules.

Edit:

My rules:

```
For<IPriceValidationRule>().Use<MaxPriceValidationRule>().Named("A");
For<IPriceValidationRule>().Use<MinPriceValidationRule>().Named("A");
For<IPriceValidationRule>().Use<MyDoublePriceValidationRule>().Named("B");
For<IPriceValidationRule>().Use<MyPriceValidationRule>().Named("B");
```

How could I use the same rule with different names? So when I say give me all instances named "X" I want to get MaxPriceValidationRule?

Comment: Named instances can only contain one instance, so defining many For-Use pairs with the same name will only cause SM to use the latest registration with the name. Also if you intend to register many instances of the same type, you should use the For-Add resistration syntax. Use indicates that the resitration is default for the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend creating your own factory. This factory would handle creating your specific instance of your class. Then injecting this factory as dependency, where your want to use your specific instance.

Comment: Is there no option in StructureMap for configuring how contructor dependencies should resolve?

Comment: There is, but I am not sure if it fits your requirements. And I dont really like that kind of functionality, because it makes DI and IoC harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which objects should be injected into an enumerable parameter using the following syntax:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(c =>
            {
                c.For<IPriceValidator>().Use<PriceValidatory>()
                    .EnumerableOf<IPriceValidationRule>().Contains(i => { 
                        i.Type<ValidationRule1>();
                        i.Type<ValidationRule2>();
                    });
            });
```

Comment: How do I get all rules that are named "A"? I tried this: For<IPriceValidator>().Use<PriceValidator>().EnumerableOf<IPriceValidationRule>().Contains(rule => rule.TheInstanceNamed("A")); But it does not work, because I get only MinPriceValidationRule. How could a instance be used by other names? So When I am asking for "A" I want MaxRule and MinRule and when I ask for "X" I want only the MaxRule? Is this possible?